# iPad - Showing "Genie" animation for views

Tags: iphone, animation

There are limited number of animations with default SDK for iPad.
I would like to implement "Genie" effect in my app.
Is there any open source library or some library that I can purchase for "Genie" effect?

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at my project at git://github.com/rmd6502/Genie.git - it's very slow right now, but improvements are forthcoming.